# Gradient Descent & Backpropagation difference b/w Embedding Layer in Keras and Word2Vec of Gensim

Tags: python, keras, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec

I was working on a Amazon Sentiment Classification dataset, where I have to predict the sentiment based on the reviews given. However I was experimenting with 2 methods, one with the normal `Embedding` layer from Keras, and this is my architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

And the next one I was trying with `Word2Vec` from `gensim.models`. Here is my code:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
word_model = Word2Vec(df['reviewText'], size=200, min_count = 1, window = 5,sg=0, negative=5)
WV_DIM = 100
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_vectors.vocab))
# we initialize the matrix with random numbers
wv_matrix = (np.random.rand(nb_words, WV_DIM) - 0.5) / 5.0
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= MAX_NB_WORDS:
        continue
    try:
        embedding_vector = word_vectors[word]
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        wv_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    except:
        pass    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_words,
                     WV_DIM,
                     mask_zero=False,
                     weights=[wv_matrix],
                     input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                     trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

But I'm unable to understand what is the difference b/w just using the `model.add(Embedding(..))` and using the `word2vec` along with `Embedding`. I want to know the Maths behind the working of Keras's `Embedding` layer and how `word2vec`+`Embedding` is working out.

I've gone through [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work) to understand how Keras embedding layer work out but I want to understand the gradient descent and backpropagation for it and also for the combination of `word2vec` and `Embedding`.

P.S. For the both the codes I've given, I have skipped the `tokenize` and `pad_sequence` part.

Comment: In your first example, the embedding layer is part of your trainable weights. For the weight update... suppose oj is a one hot vector representing word j, E is the embedding matrix, and vj is its corresponding embedding vector, therefore, vj = E*oj; you can use this for a regular weight update just like any other. In your second example, your embedding matrix has fixed values (provided by word2vec), it won't be updated.

Comment: So what is the embedding matrix, I'm not able understand :( What does it contain?

Comment: The embedding matrix is a matrix of words embeddings! Each word is represented by a vector. Let's say word 'wi' is represented by the vector 'ei' (the vector 'ei' was generated by word2vec). The embedding matrix is: E = [e1 e2 ... ei ... eN], where N is the total of words.

Comment: So when doing prediction, during training like how is the error minimized? Can you please take a small statement and give an example, like how loss is minimised using gradient descent?

Comment: Aren't you mixing things up? Error is minimized using the gradient/derivatives of the loss function, which uses the real output and the predicted output (and weights if you use regularization). This is what you use in the weights update, if weights are parameters or treinable! If you have constant parameters (such as an embedding matrix that came from word2vec), these won't do any good in the error minimization. I suggest you read the following book: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ (it has the example you want, and much more).